# How to align the width of the TextFromField with above Expended width

Tags: flutter

I have the following code. It generates an image, big long text input and two buttons. Everything is fine. However, I want to align the width of the text input field (including logo as well) to the picture above. How can I achieve this?

[Current Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUfv5.png)

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  body: SafeArea(
    top: true,
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          flex: 6,
          child: GestureDetector(
            child: Hero(
              tag: 'matchedPerson',
              child: Image.network(
                widget.imageUrl,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          flex: 2,
          child: Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: TextFormField(
              controller: _textController,
              autofocus: true,
              maxLines: null,
              expands: true,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                icon: Icon(Icons.send),
                hintText: 'Your message here',
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          flex: 1,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: [
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                child: const Text('Button 1'),
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                child: const Text('Button 2'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

Comment: can you share an image that are you trying to archive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Okay, there are many ways to achieve this.
2. As far as ı understand from codes and your description, you just need to simply add `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch` to your Column widget. This way your children will be expanded horizontally (children will fill the cross-axis)

```
    Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: [
        // your children
```

3.Then you can simple wrap your column with SizeBox widget to give them width. Such as;

```
    SizedBox(
      width: 250,
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
         // your children
```

Comment: Many thanks. This indeed made it better. This is the [current result.](https://imgur.com/2Is3Knb)

However, the TextFormField is still looking misaligned. Perhaps this is due to its padding settings ?

Comment: Removing the padding setting did the work. Thanks!